# detecting orientation changes using viewWillTransitionToSize

Tags: swift, xcode

I have read posts which say didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation is deprecated and advising using viewWillTransitionToSize.

But whenever I try to use this function e.g.

```
 override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        print("Landscape")

    } else {

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: const)
    }
```

I get an error which says Method does not override any method of its superclass.
I have tried to use the function in both view controller and its view but to no avail.

Comment: Looks like you are using an old version of Xcode (Swift 2.x). If you tag your question appropriately it makes it easier for people to help you solve your issue.

Comment: BTW boolValue is redundant

Comment: You are probably not subclassing a UIViewController or you have added it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Swift 3, the signature is (for UIViewController):

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

See if that helps.

An alternative that should give you the dimensions after rotation is `willWillLayoutSubviews()` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.(I use the former.)  BEWARE: Both may be called several times in a single rotation. Here's my code....

View Controller:

```
var initialOrientation = true
var isInPortrait = false

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if initialOrientation {
        initialOrientation = false
        if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
            isInPortrait = false
        } else {
            isInPortrait = true
        }
        // call initial layout, isInPortrait is set
    } else {
        if view.orientationHasChanged(&isInPortrait) {
            // orientation has changed, isInPortrait is set
        }
    }
}
```

UIView extension:

```
extension UIView {
    public func orientationHasChanged(_ isInPortrait:inout Bool) -> Bool {
        if self.frame.width > self.frame.height {
            if isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = false
                return true
            }
        } else {
            if !isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = true
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

16 months later I was asked if I included a typo - should it be `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. The full answer is "it depends".

- The baseline for this question is about the weakness of using `viewWillTransitionToSize`, namely, that if you are targeting iPad devices the size class **will not** change. (Also, note the *Will* piece of the override - it's triggered *before* the orientation change.
- In my experience, there is no "guarantee" the either `viewWillLayoutSubviews` *or* `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will be called only once. But my testing over the years results in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is more likely to be called only once.
- More, in the view controller lifecycle, `viewDidLoad` *will* trigger *at least two calls to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` with the initial call having a frame of `CGRect.zero`.

So if you need to know the orientation change for *autolayout* constraint activation/deactivation, `viewWillLayoutSubviews` will work fine. However, if you wish to manipulate subview frames, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is the proper place for things.

My latest project involves a `UIImageView` that uses auto layout to be as large as possible in both orientations. The `contentMode` is `scaleAspectFit`, so the image itself is automatically resized on an orientation change. The user can use subviews to 'build" a mask (both move and resize), so auto layout won't work here. More, I need to have this mask be "constrained" to the actual image.

So I need to "manually" resize/repostion the mask frame by using *both* the "will" and "did" pieces of an orientation change. Here's the code I now use. The `UIView` extension is still the same, the changes are only in `UIViewController`.

```
var initialOrientation = true
var isInPortrait = false
var orientationDidChange = false

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if initialOrientation {
        initialOrientation = false
        if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
            isInPortrait = false
        } else {
            isInPortrait = true
        }
        orientationWillChange()
    } else {
        if view.orientationHasChanged(&isInPortrait) {
            orientationWillChange()
        }
    }
}
func orientationWillChange() {
    // capture the old frame values here, storing in class variables
    orientationDidChange = true
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if orientationDidChange {
        // change frame for mask and reposition
        orientationDidChange = false
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. That prevents the warning message. I note that viewWillTransition is called before rotation has taken place. Is there an equivalent to didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation), which allows one to get dimensions after rotation?

Comment: Let me add that to my answer. It's code that works for me.

Comment: Thank you so much. I find DidLayoutSubviews works perfectly for me.

Comment: Glad to have helped out!

Comment: Looks like there's a typo: "super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()" should be "super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()"?